# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

Tags: php, html, laravel

While working with forms on my laravel project I keep getting this error I don't understand why.

It's an issue with my routes file as far as I understand it:

```
Route::post('postsmth', ['uses' => 'adminPageController@postsmth', 'as' => 'postsmth']);
```

Blade view:

```
<form action="{{ route('postsmth') }}" method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Select from the list</span>
                    <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">

                        <?php 
                        for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
                          echo "<option value='$x'>".$x."</option>";
                        } 
                        ?>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Department ID</span>
                    <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
                      <?php 
                        for ($y = 10; $y <= 20; $x++) {
                          echo "<option value='$y'>".$y."</option>";
                        } 
                        ?>

                    </select>
                </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function postmaps(Request $request) {


}
```

Comment: Where is this form located? Ie: what `route` is it located in?

Comment: app/Http/routes.php

Comment: Right, but the form itself is where? `route('postsmth')`? `route('home')`? `route('my-form')`?

Comment: I'm asking what route you take to get to the form. As in, `Route::get('my-admin-form')` inside `routes.php`? The reason I'm wondering: if you have some validation issues or another reason the form returns back to it's original route, it could be throwing this error. With just what you've provided above, it _should_ be working, so you might try looking for redirect issues which can cause issues like this.

Comment: I don't have any route for the form particulary. Only for the view that has this form. Should   I write it? Because I have a working example without it :/

Comment: Okay. So you might want to try `match` or `any` on either of those routes to see if the issue is resolved. Like: `Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'postsmth'...` or `Route::any('postsmth'...` and test from there. And no, the form itself doesn't have/need a route, the view does so you're okay there.

Comment: Can you post your controller's code? Also, the view you posted, what method uses that view? And when does the error shows? when you try to post to the `postsmth` or when you try to display the page that contains that view?

Comment: Could you post controller please

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert the error shows when I try to post the form by pressing 'submit'.

Comment: Your route says postsmth and your controller postmaps ?

Comment: @FrankProvost lol you're right. Thanks. I feel so stupid right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments it's as simple as that:

postmaps != postsmth

```
public function postsmth(Request $request) {


}
```

solves it